# Action method of commandButton not invoked during beforeunload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I looked at all the similar questions/answers with no luck. 
Here's the code for onbeforeunload event:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
        $("input[id$='signOutsubmitbtn']").click() ;
        event.returnValue = "Write something clever here..";
    };
```

The button is declared as below:

```
<h:form id="test-form">
        <h:commandButton id="signOutsubmitbtn" styleClass="RUIFW-btn-primary signout-btn" 
        value="Test S" action="#{signOffUI.doSignOut}" onclick="console.log('### test'); return true;"/>
    </h:form>
```

It works as expected in IE, but not in any other browser e.g. Chrome or FireFox. The button does gets clicked as I see debug statement on console, but does not invoke the action method. 
Clicking the button directly works as expected for all browsers.
Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Comment: in other browsers you need to return string. try `return event.returnValue = "Write something clever here..";`

Comment: thanks jcubic, tried it, no success